# Can conditional regex be used to match one field at different locations of the string depending on what it finds early on in the string?

Tags: regex, conditional-statements

Let's say I have a string that could be of the following forms:

```
asdf - 10.0.0.1 [stuff] [xRelevantStuffx]

asdf [yRelevantStuffy] 10.0.0.1 [stuff] [xRelevantStuffx]
```

Basically in the above scenario, what I want to do is to have 4 different groups, one that would match the following in each scenario:

- Group 1: `asdf`
- Group 3: `10.0.0.1`
- Group 4: `stuff`

But for Group 2, I would want it to be different depending on if that hypen `-` character shows up early on or not.  If it does show up, I want to have Group 2 match `xRelevantStuffx`. But if it is a non hyphen value, I don't care about what comes in later in the string and want it to match on `yRelevantStuffy`.

Does RegEx have enough capabilities with condition matching in order for me to accomplish this purely through regex, or am I going to try and find a different solution here that leverages outside string manipulation/logic?

Comment: Just setup capture groups for everything and then choose what to retain in your application logic.

Comment: normally this is what I'd do, however this is for a splunk transformation.conf edit which basically just expects a single regex statement in order to perform a field transform.  There might be other workarounds for me but I was hoping maybe this is something I could use via some fancy lookaheads or lookbehinds?  Problem is all the tutorials I'm finding online don't really seem to utilize them in a way that I'm looking to do, but it feels like maybe it could be possible?

Comment: Group numbers always count from left to right. I'm not sure there's any way to make group 2 sometimes match something to the right of group 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to capture inside a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and make the part from hyphen until last brackets optional. A lookahead is a zero length assertion and allows to do actions where it is placed.

```
^(\w+) (?=(?:-.*)?\[([^]]+)\]).*? ((?:\d+\.){3}\d+) \[([^]]+)\]
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/KFcQT3/1) (attach `.*` to the pattern [if you need full match as well](https://www.regex101.com/r/KFcQT3/2)).

---

If you need more groups but use the same group index in alternation, another idea would be to capture inside a [branch reset group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) where capturing group alternatives share the same group index.

```
^(\w+) (?=(?|-.*\[([^]]+)\]|\[([^]]+)\])).*? ((?:\d+\.){3}\d+) \[([^]]+)\]
```

[Another demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wZKcbc/2) (*branch reset* is available in PCRE and JGsoft V2).

---

Further at least in PCRE there is the `J` [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (PCRE_DUPNAMES) available which allows duplicate names for subpatterns. I don't know which of those ideas would work best in your environment.

Comment: You're awesome, thank you this is exactly what I'm looking for!